# CSV indentation and Proper language in Python

Tags: python

I want to return the list that comes out with the print function into a CSV list.

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(146):
    r = requests.get(("http://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/trends/{}").format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile('/atlanta-ga/')):
        if 'trends' not in link.get('href'):
            link = (link.get('href'))
            results = (("http://www.yellowpages.com{}?page=").format(link))
            import csv

            with open('Catagories', 'w') as myfile:
                wr = csv.writer(myfile)
                wr.writerow([results])

            print(results)
```

The purpose of this should be very apparent

Comment: You should open the file and create `csv.writer` just once, not every time through the loop. Then you call `writerow` in the loop.

Comment: Every time you do `open('Catagories', 'w')` you overwrite everything that was in the file. Since its inside the loop, you end up with only the last row processed in the file.

Answer (score 0):

@tdelaney is right: every time you open the file with "w", you're overwritting the previous text.

The fix is to use "a" instead:

```
with open('Catagories', 'a') as myfile:
    ...
```

Check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open